# Custom DelegatingHandler unsuccessful status code handling

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a custom DelegatingHandler that scans calls to the back-end watching for 401 (cookie expired) and redirects the browser to relogin.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    // Server returned 401 Unauthorized, redirect to login page
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        _authenticationStateProvider.SignIn();

    return response;
}
```

The problem is that before the redirect happens in the browser, an unhandled exception is thrown due to the 401.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

This results in a momentary Blazor error bar at the bottom of the page.  What is the best way to handle this?  I don't want to wrap up every http call in a try/catch.  Should I be looking at Error Boundaries?  Is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used `try` to catch the Unauthorized and Forbidden exceptions since those are the ones I'm redirecting on but since I have many http calls, I decided to create a service instead that wraps the calls and just return the data I need or an empty result. As for error boundaries, I have an `<ErrorBoundary>` set at the page level but this is for unhandled exceptions so I don't recommend them for this.

Here's an example of my solution:

### Service

```
  public class MyHttpService
  {    
    public MyHttpService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
      _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetData<T>(string requestUri) where T : new()
    {
       var http = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SecureClient");

       try
       {
          var response = await http.GetAsync(requestUri);
          var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();
          return result;
       }
       catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode is Unauthorized || ex.StatusCode is Forbidden)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("redirecting");
          return new T();
       }
     }

    //....put, post, delete methods

  }
```

---

### Component

```
     protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
       var students= await _httpService.GetData<List<Students>>("api/students");
     }
```

---

### Custom delegate handler

You can call *EnsureSuccessStatusCode()* before returning your response so it
can throw the exception, if not successful, and go to the catch block in the
service.

```
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response;
```